# How to pass date as string in sql date field and select data where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is: I'm trying to select data whose date is my expression.

For example:

```
select * 
from cutting 
where cut_date = 14-07-2017
```

But it shows an error:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

In SQL Server.

Please help I am just learning basics of SQL

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surround(enclose) the date with `'`:

```
 select * from cutting where cut_date ='14-07-2017'
```

Or better yet, the proper way is to set the date format yourself:

```
select * from cutting where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cut_date,10) = '2017-07-14'
```

Or:

```
select * from cutting where FORMAT(cut_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2017-07-14'
```

Comment: Thanks For Reply But i also tried that but it shows an error folllowing:

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: ya sure but time is not completed to accept your answer and thanks again

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the comment. I removed that line from my answer.

Comment: You should not use capital 'Y' and 'D' for formatting in sql, format string is 'yyyy-MM-dd', this will work select * from cutting where FORMAT(cut_date,'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2017-07-14'

Comment: @JaniDevang Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.

Replace date in `where` clause with "YYYY-MM-DD" format;

```
select * 
from cutting 
where cut_date = "2017-07-14"
```

Comment: SQL Server **DOES NOT** keep `DATETIME` columns with any specific string format - `DATETIME` is a **8-byte binary value** in SQL Server. The preferred format for dates as string literals that will work with any language/regional settings is the modified **ISO-8601** format: `YYYYMMDD` (no dashes, nothing!)